# Facebook api: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request with

Tags: php, json, facebook-graph-api

I have been looking on stack and the facebook documentation on how to do a facebook api call to get a pages status messages.

So Far I have this:

```
$url = "https://graph.facebook.com/dogfishheadbeer/statuses?fields=message,updated_time&limit=5";
$url_with_token = $url . "?access_token={$access_token}";
$facebookData = json_decode(file_get_contents($url_with_token));
```

I am not sure how to get my access token though. I went to the facebook api explorer here:

https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

and I clicked "Gett acces token" but hwen used in my php cpde I get this error:

```
Warning: file_get_contents(https://graph.facebook.com/dogfishheadbeer/statuses?fields=message,updated_time&limit=5?access_token=myAccesToken) [function.file-get-contents]: failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request
```

I also read acces tokens expire and my website needs to be able to refresh them. I am a bit lost on what to try next, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Look into using facebook fql. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't be able to use the same access token as the one from the explorer. What you need to do is create your own app on Facebook. 
It will give you applicationId and applicationSecret which you can then use to get access token for your api calls.

Have a look at those getting started guides here: 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/login-for-canvas/
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/

Comment: Do I need all the bells and whistles from this example to just do a simple get request?

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/getting-started/

Comment: If the data you require from facebook requires authentication yes, I'm afraid you need to go through those, so you can get access token and then make requests freely.

Comment: For some reason you need an access token for page statuses when they are already public...

Answer (score 2):

Your URL is invalid.

The resulting URL will be:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/dogfishheadbeer/statuses?fields=message,updated_time&limit=5?access_token={$access_token}
                                                            second question mark here ^^
```

This line will fix that particular issue, although it may not be the only problem:

```
$url_with_token = $url . "&access_token={$access_token}";
//                       ^^ ampersand instead
```

Comment: thanks! that was a dumb mistake on my part, I still need to figure out the access token thing though.